# Probability of overwriting repeatedly chosen $\binom{n}{k}$ elements.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose we have an array $M$ of memory cells with $n$ cells represented by $M = [c_1;...;c_n]$, and suppose we will repeat the following process in every time $t$:

- Choose a new (unique for every $t$) message $m_t$;
- Uniformly choose a subset $C_t$ of size $k$, among these $n$ cells:  $C_t = [c_{t1};...;c_{tk}] \subset [c_1;...;c_n]$;
- Copy the message $m_t$ on every memory cell in the subset $C_{t}$: $[c_{t1}=m_t;...;c_{tk}=m_t]$;

By repeating the above experiment, there is a probability of overwriting a cell: update an already written cell with a new message. So, in a after time $t+i$, we can lose some (or all) message copies on $C_t$.

**So, what the probability of at least one message $m_t$, written in $t$, remain in any of $c_{tk}$ cell after $i$ more repetition of this experiment?**

Please, I need some help in how to make an analysis of the relation of the size of memory $n$, the size of the subset of copies $k$, and the number of repetitions $i$.

Comment: If approximation is OK, the easiest way is to assume each copy of the msg has independently a $k/n$ prob of being erased per timeslot. This has a closed form solution, and is probably quite accurate for $k \ll n$. However, this is not exact because the erasures are _dependent_ - one copy being erased actually slightly _reduces_ the prob of another copy being erased in the same timeslot.

Comment: If you want the exact answer, this can be modeled as a Markov Chain with $k+1$ states, $\{0, 1, 2, \dots, k\}$, representing no. of copies that are still left. It is possible, but tedious, to calculate all the transition probabilities, and there's probably no closed form solution, but you can calculate it exactly numerically.

Comment: @antkam, thanks for your feedback. But, if we look at each copy, _per si_, isn't the chance of it be erased equals to $1- (\binom{n-1}{k}/\binom{n}{k})$? Look, if we keep a cell, it remains $n-1$ others to place our $k$ new messages. What am I losing?

Comment: Your expression simplifies to $k/n$ :) and yes that is indeed the prob of a given copy being erased in one timeslot.  The problem is that erasures are dependent.  E.g. Consider $n=3, k=2$.  You start with $2$ copies and in the next timeslot each copy is erased with prob $2/3$.  However, conditioned on copy A being erased, copy B is erased with prob only $1/2$, whereas conditioned on copy A being not-erased, copy B is erased with prob $1$ (certainty).  So you cannot e.g. simply multiply $\frac23 \times \frac23 = \frac49$ and call that the prob of both being erased.

Comment: @antkam. You are correct. Isn't so hard for $k=4,8,12...$. I'm looking at $k <10; n=128,256,512...$. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For $k<10$ but $n\ge 128$, I think the approximation will be very good.  If you're interested I can write that up as an answer.

Comment: @antkam, Yes, I'm interested. If you can, it will be nice give an aswer to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approximate solution.  (My gut feel is that this should be a good approximation if $k \ll n$...?)

The approximation: assume each copy is erased independently.  (In the exact model, erasures of different copies are "negatively" correlated, i.e. conditioning on a copy $A$ being erased at time $t$ will slightly *decrease* the probability that a copy $B$ will also be erased at time $t$.)

- At any time, a surviving copy will be erased with prob $p = {k \over n}$.

  - I.e. it continues to survive with prob $1 - p$.
- A copy will survive for $i$ timeslots with prob $(1 - p)^i$.

  - I.e. a copy will fail to survive for $i$ timeslots with prob $1 - (1 - p)^i$.  (This is the prob it will be overwritten during any of those $i$ timeslots.)
- No more surviving copies means all $k$ copies fail to survive.  This is where we bring in the independence approximation: the prob that all $k$ copies fail to survive $\approx (1 - (1-p)^i)^k$.

  - In the exact model, conditioning on a copy $A$ failing to survive will slightly *decrease* the prob that copy $B$ also fails to survive.  So my guess is that the true value of $Prob(\text{no survivors}) $ is slightly $< (1 - (1 - p)^i)^k$.
- Finally, prob that some copy will survive $\approx \fbox{$1 - (1 - (1 - p)^i)^k$}$